# Google Calendar API's 'gapi.client.load' function takes long time to load

Tags: javascript, api, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google Calendar API to retrieve all events from a public calendar within 24-hour time span, and output them to the console (for now).

My code appears to functioning, but after page load, it takes a long time for the request to complete (varies from 600-2000 milliseconds).

Using `performance.now()`, I've nailed it down to the function that loads the client library interface -- `gapi.client.load`.

Is there a more efficient way to load this, so it doesn't take so long? Or other ideas on how to retrieve these events quickly? Below is the code I'm using.

```
var Hours = {

clientId : 'CLIENTID',
apiKey : 'APIKEY',
calendarID : 'CALENDARID',
userTimeZone : 'Chicago',
scopes : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',

handleClientLoad : function() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(this.apiKey);
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: this.clientId, scope: this.scopes, immediate: true}, this.handleAuthResult);

},

handleAuthResult : function(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {

        Hours.makeAPICall();

    }
}, 

makeAPICall : function() {
    var today = new Date(); 
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (24*60*60*1000));

    var t0 = performance.now();
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () {

        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            'calendarId' : Hours.calendarID,
            'timeZone' : Hours.userTimeZone, 
            'singleEvents': true, 
            'timeMin': today.toISOString(),
            'timeMax': tomorrow.toISOString(),
            'maxResults': 10, 
            'orderBy': 'startTime'});

        var t1 = performance.now();
        console.log(t1-t0);

        request.execute(function (resp) {
            for(var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                console.log(resp.items[i].start);
                console.log(resp.items[i].end);
                console.log('---');
            }
        });
    });
}
}

var initHours = function() {
    Hours.handleClientLoad();
}
```

Comment: you realize that these calls are going to a webserver right?  I don't think that's slow.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but was hopeful there might be a more quicker way to do it regardless.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I think it would be a lot better if `gapi.client.load` could cache the resources better. It would be great if someone found a work around.